# React: How to display JSON key value pairs with line breaks?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I have the following component with a function called `onClickBtn()` that contains another function called `textBuilder()` which iterated through a JSON object filled with data from a form. I am using an email service to programatically send an email when the submit button is clicked. The only issue is that my email's `Body` value ends up looking like this in the email:

```
name: Dean age: 26 email: dean@aol.com styles: Color locations: Right Leg specificLocation: fasdfasdfa description: fdghjdghj budgets: $1000-$1500 days: Wednesday months: June
```

Instead of:

```
name: Dean 

age: 26 

email: dean@aol.com 

styles: Color 

locations: Right Leg 

specificLocation: fasdfasdfa 

description: fdghjdghj 

budgets: $1000-$1500 

days: Wednesday 

months: June
```

Below is my component. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  button: {  margin: theme.spacing(1), },
  input: { display: 'none', },
}));

export default function ContainedButtons(props) {
  const classes = useStyles();  

  const onClickBtn = () => {

    const textBuilder = () => {
      var doc = "";
      for (const key in props.values) {
       doc += key + ": " + props.values[key] + "\n";      
      }
      return doc;
    } 

    window.Email.send({
      Host : "smtp.elasticemail.com",
      Username : "dfmmalaw@gmail.com",
      Password : "d2296492-2689-49f7-ae3d-584f1507d23a",
      To : 'dfmmalaw@gmail.com',
      From : "dfmmalaw@gmail.com",
      Subject : "This is the subject",
      Body : textBuilder()
  }).then(
    message => alert(message)
  );
  };

    return (
      <div>
        <Button variant="contained" color="primary" className={classes.button} disabled = {!props.isEnabled} type="submit" onClick={onClickBtn}>
          Submit
        </Button>
      </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: It'll likely be because your email client is rendering the content as HTML. So newlines are just converted to spaces. Try it with a break element, like so:  `doc += key + ": " + props.values[key] + "<br/>"; `

Comment: Hmmm... Good call...  Let me try that.

Comment: Awesome! Worked like a charm. Can you convert your comment to an answer so I can select it?

Answer (score 0):

It's because your email client is rendering the content as HTML. So newlines are just converted to spaces. Try it with a break element, like so:

```
doc += key + ": " + props.values[key] + "<br/>";
```